# How can I get the value in a hash of the response of POST request on Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now, I am working on a project using post request on Ruby.
I could get the response with the code below.

```
  def send_param(param)
    uri = URI.parse('https:~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
    response = https.post(uri.path, param.to_query)
    print response.body
  end
```

And response.body looks like something like this

```
{"result": {"id":1111, "name": John}}
```

Now, I need to get the value of John above.
it will be something like this.

```
response["name"]
```

but I can't get the value as expected.
So I want you to help me, if you can.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [parse](https://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/parse) it and fetch the result after it using the [`dig`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig) method.

```rb
def send_param(param)
  uri = URI.parse('https:~~~~~~~~~~~~')
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
  response = https.post(uri.path, param.to_query)
  JSON.parse(response.body)
end

result = send_param({})
result.dig('result', 'name')
```